# fixed menubar css on zoom in and out

Tags: css

menu in webpage when zoomed in and out doesnt stay fixed to header image  shown in figure:

[image]

the css script for this one is as follows
    #navmenu{
    z-index:99999;
    margin-top:40px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    min-width: 90%;
    width:950px;

```
 }

 #navMenu li {
  float:left;
  color:#ececec;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:80px;
 }

 #navMenu ul {
  width:970px;
  font-size:16px;
  color:#000000;
 }


#navMenu li a{

height:15px;
float:left; display:inline;
font-weight:700;
float:left;
color:#707070;
display: block;
padding: 8px 12px;
text-decoration: none;display: block;
padding: 8px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
background-image: url(img/image_menubutton.JPG);
border-right:1px solid white;
margin-right:12px;
font-family:"Georgia",Georgia,Serif;
 font-weight:900;
font-size:19px;
text-align: center;
  zoom: 1;
  max-width: 30%;

  }
 #navmenu li.item1{background-image: url(img/about.JPG);}



#navmenu li a:hover {
    color:33CCFF;
}
```

what is the solution to this?

Comment: This is not a fixed positioned menubar, this is an absolute positioned menubar.

Comment: Hi A.K .yes i have written position:absolute; in css but still why its not working??

Comment: See [position: absolute ? fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)

Comment: You should provide some html or a jsedit or similar

Comment: why css properties are mentioned twice for links? font-weight:700; font-weight:900; display:block??display:inline?

Answer (score 1):

if you use position:fixed; then it will not move when scrolled which is what i assume you are looking for, also when zoomed same thing, it will stay position fixed to where you want it , add maybe top:0; left:0;  depending on where you want this to be positioned at-- maybe try adding some html ? other than that this is about all i can help you with

```
 #navmenu{ 
  z-index:99999; 
  margin-top:40px; 
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  min-width: 90%; 
  width:950px;
}

 #navMenu li {
  color:#ececec;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:80px;
 }

 #navMenu ul {
  width:970px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  font-size:16px;
  color:#000000;
 }


#navMenu li a{
 position:fixed;
 height:15px;
 font-weight:700;
 float:left;
 color:#707070;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-image: url(img/image_menubutton.JPG);
 border-right:1px solid white;
 margin-right:12px;
 font-family:"Georgia",Georgia,Serif;
 font-size:19px;
 text-align: center;
 zoom: 1;
 max-width: 30%;
}
```